# ngModel is not selecting any option in select element angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am working with ngModel in select options but it is not working properly. by default no value is selected using ngModel.

Sample:

```ts
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="select">Client Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedFeesEntry.client" name="selectedFeesEntry.client.name" (change)="onClientNameChange(selectedFeesEntry.client.name)">
            <option *ngFor="let cl of clientList" [ngValue]="cl">{{cl.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, **clientList** is an array of objects and I am using a web service to push elements in this array. **selectedFeesEntry** is an object and using another web service for this object. By default when the component is loaded then it should select a default value.

sample TS:

```ts
selectedFeesEntry: any;
clientList: Array<any> = [];

    getFeesData(headers){
        this.logsProvider.getAllFeeEntries(headers)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.selectedFeesEntry = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
            },
            error => {
            }
        );
    }

    getClients(headers){
        this.logsProvider.getAllClients(headers)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.clientList = JSON.parse(data['_body']); 
            },
            error => {
            }
        );
    }
```

Sample Json:

1. selectedFeesEntry ->

```ts
{
    "id":1,
    "date":"2017-08-05 03:01:00",
    "amount":500.0,
    "client":
    {
        "id":21,
        "name":"client Fee1",
        "addressee":"xyz",
        "address1":"address1 "
    }
}
```

2. clientList ->

```ts
[
   {
      "id":8,
      "name":"client1 updated",
      "addressee":"client1",
      "address1":"new add "
   },
   {
      "id":14,
      "name":"client4",
      "addressee":"xyz",
      "address1":"some street at some city updated ",
   },
   {
      "id":18,
      "name":"new client",
      "addressee":"abc",
      "address1":"add1",
   }
]
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Plunk: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpllrj?embed=1&file=app/app.component.css

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post also your ts code?

Comment: Show a sample of clientList array and what is the type of `selectedFeesEntry.client`

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I have added ts code

Comment: @pritesh Sample json is also added please look into this

Comment: Can you replicate thia in stackblitz ?

Comment: @RahulSingh added a plunk

Comment: Your selected option is not one of the displayed options. It might be similar, ave the same fields, with the same values, but that's not sufficient. It must be one of the option values.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah because i am getting the response from two web services ... but i think same object is passed from the service so it should work... Is there any way how can i achieve this

Comment: I am facing same issue at many places ... need to fix it

Comment: It can be the same object if you receive them from two different services. Again, the fact that they look identical is irrelevant. They must be **the exact, same objects**. I.e. `a === b` must be true.

Comment: yeah when i compared both objects I.e. a===b then they are not equal ... Any idea how can we match those objects ?.... Look identical

Comment: Find the one in the collection of options that "looks identical" to what you want selected, and set **that** object as the selected option.